# Import paths between angular styling projects not working as intended

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I read in the Angular documentation that if I add in the angular.json:

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "src/style-paths"
  ]
}
```

By doing that, I can use imports like this:

```
// A relative path works
@import '../style-paths/variables';
// But now this works as well
@import 'variables';
```

My problem is that I have 3 different style folders, let's say folder1-styles, folder2-styles and common-styles. In want to use shortee imports for the folder1 and 2 styles when I import stylesheets from the common-styles folder.

I used the stylePreprocessorOptions and included a common-styles path there, and after changing my relative paths, the imports look like this:

```
@import '~scss/sub-folder1/stylesheetname';
```

Although the code seems to work in my code editor and the imports go where they are needed, after I run the **yarn sass** command in the styles folder, I get an error and see that it tries to get my imports from node_modules. I think this is due to "~" being at the import statement, but without it, it does not see my common-styles (only by relative path, but they are way too long).

Are there any extra configs I would need to check?
I would appreciate any help on what should I try, or what I have done wrong.

Comment: What did you put into the includePaths, and where are the folders located relative to your src folder?

Comment: I have a folder named projects, in which there are more folders. 2 apps, 3 libs and 3 style folders. Being 2 apps, there are 2 src folders, one in each app. Considering this, where do you think would be best to place the path or paths. I am guessing that because I use the path in 4 places I would need it in more than 1 place. Currently, I have it declared everywhere in the angular.json to see if it works. In both apps and all 6 lib projectTypes.

Comment: Without using the includePaths, I couldn't use the import as mentioned in the description with "~sccs/etc.". And the imports work fine VIA the code editor, if I click them, they go where they are imported from. The problem is that when I start the apps, I get imports errors. And if I go in the style folders and check yarn sass, it seems that it tries to make the imports from node_modules instead of the path specified by me.

Comment: If these are all using the same angular.json, I think it will work if you use includePaths that begin with the projects folder, e.g. `"projects/app1/src/styles"` and `"projects/app2/src/styles"`.  As far as I am aware the paths should always be relative to the angular.json file and will apply to all sub-projects that use that file.

The `~` is used to reference styles in the node_modules folder, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: The problem is that these apps are very big (marketplace). And the app directories do not contain any styles, they are made after the Spartacus guidelines, where the scss files are not near the angular components anymore, but in different style directories. But the import paths from the common-style directories are too long, ex: '../../../../../../folder/subfolder1/subfolder2/stylesheet.scss'

Comment: The angular.json file is in the root of the project, and there are 8 big directories. (3 are style directories, and I want to import stuff from the common-style one to the other 2 app specific directories).

Comment: After checking through the angular.json docs again I've found that the stylePreprocessorOptions is per project, so you will need to make sure you are setting it for all projects.  I'm not sure why this setting wouldn't work with a long path as long as it is relative to the angular.json file, but an easy way to get the files into a subfolder relative to the angular.json would be to use a symlink.